# Calling a Javascript function from a hash value with namespaces

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

I currently have this code to call a function from a hash value on page load:

```
$(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    window[hash]();
});
```

This works great.

However, my Javascript in namespaced like so:

```
    var help = {
            faq: function () {
                //do stuff
            },

            newFeatures: function () {
                //do stuff
            }
    }
```

My function that I listed up top does not work for namespaced javascript. I've tried manually adding the namespace to the front (so `var hash = "help." + window.location.hash.substring(1);`) but that did not work.

How can I navigate around this issue without removing my Javascript from a namespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    window.help[hash]();
});
```

In JavaScript dot notation and square brackets are interchangeable, as long as the key is a valid JavaScript identifier. (Otherwise, you have to use square brackets.)

So you could also do this (although dot notation is more readable):

```
$(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    window["help"][hash]();
});
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you! I will accept this as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a similar method where I store object values in a hash.

My technique:

- use a dot in the hash to show the hierarchy - in your case: #help.faq
- run a script to convert the dot notation and retrieve the actual value

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Kn4w2/1/

Code sample:

```
var hashArray=hash.split("."),
    myMethod=window;
for (var i=0;i<hashArray.length;i++){
        myMethod=myMethod[hashArray[i]];
}
```

The only constraint is that of course your method names should not contain a dot.

Comment: What I really like about this solution is that it easily allows for multiple namespaces and I can reuse the same functionality. I appreciate your input. Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely! I actually use it for general cases with more than two levels (for example #help.faq.question1), but then the code becomes more complicated as you need to add validation steps.

Comment: I'm actually considering turning a web project into a single-page app and a set-up like this would make mapping to controllers and actions pretty darn easy with javascript and ajax.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not really a fan, but 'eval' might work:

```
eval(hash + "()");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pGktd/